# How to solve Fuzzy Differential Equations

Tags: differential-equations

How to solve Fuzzy Differential Equations using DSolve or NDSolve, Or Differential Equations with fuzzy number as initial conditions

Comment: A good starting place could be the [Fuzzy Logic package](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/fuzzylogic/).